# Separate out React Native Javascript Runtime to run javascript in native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, v8, javascriptcore, mobile-development

Is there an easy way to get the javascript functionality out of React Native without the view portion? I looked through the source and found what seems to be the relevant pieces (namely the [cxxreact](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/3940f06211faf4fc34270d5cf2c5d57d43ed762e/ReactCommon/cxxreact) package), but am having a hard time following how it fits together.

I am trying to run javascript in a native app without a webview. I've found J2V8 and AndroidJSCore, but they seem like they're going to require a lot of work to make generic enough to run arbitrary javascript.

I believe React Native already solved this (especially surrounding api calls) and would like to reuse that portion. Is there anyone who has done something similar or can point me to something more full-featured than just J2V8 or AndroidJSCore?